# Keycloak Offline Access token with 'refresh_token' grant_type

Tags: keycloak, access-token

I'm trying to get an Offline Access from Keycloak, with the following request:

```
curl -X POST https://<domain>/auth/realms/public/protocol/openid-connect/token 
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  -d 'grant_type=refresh_token'
  -d "refresh_token=<token>"
  -d 'scope=offline_access'
  -d 'client_id=<id>'
  -d 'client_secret=<secret>'
```

The `scope` in the response isn't `offline_access` as I expected, but `openid`, and also the number of Offline Tokens is not updated in the admin console.

```
{
  "access_token": <access token>,
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_expires_in": 84884,
  "refresh_token": <refresh token>,
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "id_token": <id token>,
  "not-before-policy": 0,
  "session_state": <state>,
  "scope": "openid"
}
```

How can I get Offline Access tokens using `grant_type` `'refresh_token'`?

Note that I'm able to get them using `grant_type` `password`, but would prefer not to use that, because:

- I'm already using a refresh token in my app, but I don't have access to the password
- I'm not sure how that would even work with Social Login and 2FA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually offline_access needs to be specified in the original authorization request - at the time of the delegation - which in some setups also involves user consent to use tokens offline.

Try getting the refresh token like this, when completing authorization:

```
curl -X POST https://<domain>/auth/realms/public/protocol/openid-connect/token 
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code'
  -d 'code=<code>'
  -d "redirect_uri=<uri>'
  -d 'scope=openid offline_access'
  -d 'client_id=<id>'
  -d 'client_secret=<secret>'
```

Then omit the scope parameter in the refresh token grant request that you posted. The scope parameter is not usually specified in this message. If it is then it can only be used to reduce scopes in the delegation. That is, you cannot silently get new scopes that a user did not consent to.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, it makes sense in retrospect. I'm using `keycloak-js`, managed to redirect to login, with the 'offline-access' scope included by calling `.logout({ redirectUri: this.keycloak.createLoginUrl({ redirectUri: window.location.origin, scope: 'offline_access' })`. After logging in, I can see in the admin console that an Offline Token has been created.